# How to adapt my custom multimedia video controls - HTML5/CSS3?

Tags: html, css

I am creating a design of controls to personalize the reproduction of videos, having some errors in the design there is a disorder in the design and even more when it comes to visualizing in different type of responsive screen.

In the design of the **Speed** as I can order them with a drop-down menu as shown in the following example image:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

How can I give the correct style to the progress bar similar to the following image:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

And carry an adaptive order similar to it.

**My code complete:**

```css
    .seeker {
        position: relative;
        width: 54%;
        margin: 0 1%;
        display: inline-block;
        margin-right: 5px;
        margin: 0 10px;
    }

    .trackbar {
        position: absolute;
        width: 100%;
        height: 1px;
        top: 12px;
        z-index: -2;
        background: rgba(255,255,255,0.7);
    }
    .progressbar {
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
        top: 12px;
        width: 0;
        height: 1px;
        border: 0;
        background-color: red;
        color: red;
        z-index: 0;
        pointer-events: none;
    }

    .content-video-player {
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 40px;
        /*background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left,rgba(0,0,0,.7) 0px,rgba(0,0,0,.7) 95px,transparent 95px,transparent 98px,rgba(0,0,0,.7) 98px);*/
        background: rgba(0,0,0,.7);
        -webkit-transition: bottom .4s ease-in;
    }

    .content-video-player div.btn {
        width: 95px;
        text-align: center;
        float: left;
    }

    .btnPlay::after {
        content: "";
        background-image: url(http://svgshare.com/i/3um.svg);
        width: 50px;
        height: 50px;
        display: inline-block;
        background-size: cover;
        position: relative;
        top: -7px;
    }

    .btnStop::after {
        content: "";
        background-image: url(http://svgshare.com/i/3vz.svg);
        width: 65px;
        height: 65px;
        display: inline-block;
        background-size: cover;
        position: relative;
        top: -7px;
    }

    .video-time-player {
        float: right;
        color: #ccc;
        text-align: center;
        width: 15%;
    }

    .volume {
        position: relative;
        cursor: pointer;
        width: 70px;
        height: 10px;
        float: right;
        margin-top: 10px;
        margin-right: 10px;
    }

    .volumeBar {
        display: block;
        height: 30%;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        background-color: #a4c9ec;
        z-index: 10;
    }

    .sound, .btnFS {
        border: none;
        float: right;
    }

    .sound::after {
        content: "";
        background-image: url(http://svgshare.com/i/3v6.svg);
        width: 45px;
        height: 40px;
        display: inline-block;
        background-size: cover;
        position: relative;
        top: -4px;
    }

    .btnFS::after {
        content: "";
        background-image: url(http://svgshare.com/i/3u5.svg);
        width: 25px;
        height: 25px;
        display: inline-block;
        background-size: cover;
        position: relative;
        top: 6px;
    }
```

```html
    <!-- Container of the controls vidio players -->
    <div class="content-video-player">
     <div class="btnPlay btn" title="Play/Pause video"></div>
     <div class="btnStop btn" title="Stop video"></div>
     <div class="spdText btn">Speed: </div>
     <div class="btnx1 btn text selected" title="Normal speed">x1</div>
     <div class="btnx3 btn text" title="Fast forward x3">x3</div>
     <div id="seeker" class="seeker">
      <div class="trackbar"></div>
            <div id="progressbar" class="progressbar" style="width: 114.7px;">
                <span class="bufferBar"></span>
                <span class="timeBar"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="video-time-player">
       <span class="current">00:03</span> / 
       <span class="duration">00:03</span> 
      </div>
        </div>
        <div class="btnFS" title="Switch to full screen"></div>
        <div class="volume" title="Set volume">
            <span class="volumeBar" style="width: 84.2857%;"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="sound sound2" title="Mute/Unmute sound"></div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The player layout is mainly 3 components (`display: inline-table`) within `.content-video-player` (`display:table`):

```
.playbackComponent | .timeComponent | .modComponent
```

<kbd>▶</kbd> ] [ <kbd>⏸</kbd> ] [ <kbd>X</kbd> ] |_____ **07:22**/**15:01** | <kbd>🔉</kbd>||||||| <kbd>**⛶**</kbd>

The controls in each of the components have `display:table-cell` for a stable linear layout and `position:absolute` for finer grain adjustments. Included is a menu to adjust playbackRate, just hover over the 3rd button from the left <kbd>X</kbd>

### Demo

```css
*,
*::after,
*::before {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0 none rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}

body {
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.content-video-player>* {
  display: inline-table;
}

.content-video-player {
  position: relative;
  transform: translateY(68vh);
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px !important;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .7);
  transition: bottom .4s ease-in;
  display: table;
  table-layout: fixed;
}

.seeker {
  position: absolute;
  width: 30%;
  display: table-cell;
  margin: 0 5px;
  top: calc(50% - 6px);
  left: 100px;
}

.trackbar {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 1px;
  top: 12px;
  z-index: -2;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
}

.progressbar {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 12px;
  width: 0;
  height: 1px;
  border: 0;
  background-color: red;
  color: red;
  z-index: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.content-video-player button.btn {
  width: 48px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  display: table-cell;
}

.btnPlay::after {
  content: "";
  background-image: url(http://svgshare.com/i/3um.svg);
  width: 48px;
  height: 48px;
  display: table-cell;
  background-size: cover;
  position: absolute;
  top: -4px;
}

.btnStop::after {
  content: "";
  background-image: url(http://svgshare.com/i/3vz.svg);
  width: 56px;
  height: 56px;
  display: table-cell;
  background-size: cover;
  position: absolute;
  left: 25px;
  top: calc(50% - 28px);
}

.btnSpd {
  transform: translateX(-35px);
  height: 48px;
  width: 48px;
  font-size: 24px;
  top: calc(50% - 24px);
}

.video-time-player {
  position: absolute;
  color: #ccc;
  text-align: center;
  left: 11.5em;
  font-size: .3em;
  width: auto;
  min-width: 90px;
}

.video-time-player>* {
  display: inline-block;
}

.volume {
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 80px;
  height: 10px;
  right: -5em;
  top: 17px;
}

.volumeBar {
  display: block;
  height: 30%;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #a4c9ec;
  z-index: 10;
}

.sound,
.btnFS {
  border: none;
}

.sound::after {
  content: "";
  background-image: url(http://svgshare.com/i/3v6.svg);
  width: 45px;
  height: 40px;
  display: table-cell;
  background-size: cover;
  position: absolute;
  top: 4px;
  left: 25.5em;
}

.btnFS::after {
  content: "";
  background-image: url(http://svgshare.com/i/3u5.svg);
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  right: 5px;
  display: table-cell;
  background-size: cover;
  position: absolute;
  top: 12px;
}

.speed {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  max-height: 0;
  transition: max-height 1s;
}

.speed:hover,
.btnSpd:hover .speed {
  display: inline-table;
  list-style: none;
  max-height: 300px;
  transition: max-height 1s;
  top: -170px;
}

.cmp {
  width: 30%
}
```

```html
<!-- Container of the controls vidio players -->

<main class='content-video-player'>
  <section class="cmp playbackComponent" style='display:inline-table'>
    <button class="btnPlay btn" title="Play/Pause video"></button>
    <button class="btnStop btn" title="Stop video"></button>
    <button class="btnSpd btn">X 
    <ul class='speed'>
      <li>x3.0</li>
      <li>x2.5</li>
      <li>x2.0</li>
      <li>x1.5</li>
      <li>x1.0</li>
      <li>x0.5</li>
    </ul>
    </button>
  </section>
  <section class='cmp timeComponent' style='display:inline-table'>
    <div id="seeker" class="seeker">
      <div class="trackbar"></div>
      <div id="progressbar" class="progressbar" style="width: 114.7px;">
        <span class="bufferBar"></span>
        <span class="timeBar"></span>
      </div>
      <time class="video-time-player">
       <b class="current">00:03</b> / 
       <b class="duration">00:03</b> 
      </time>
    </div>

  </section>

  <section id='cmp ModComponent' style='display:inline-table'>
    <div class="volume" title="Set volume">
      <span class="volumeBar" style="width: 84.2857%;"></span>
    </div>
    <button class="btn sound sound2" title="Mute/Unmute sound"></button>
    <button class="btn btnFS" title="Switch to full screen"></button>
  </section>
</main>
```

Comment: I like the new practice, it serves me a lot as a reference to have other options.

Comment: I have a new question similar to it, almost the same disorder of the design of this question you think you can help me but this time retaining the same structure of the HTML design that the change to correct is only in the code jquery or the code css.

Comment: [this is my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47403023/how-to-create-an-video-player-in-jquery-css3) you can look at it please or it is necessary to update this question.